# jQuery not working as expected on HTTPS Internet explorer

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

When I try to run my code on any other webbrowsers apart from the Internet explorer it works fine. But when I try to run the code on Internet explorer I do get an alert box saying HERE along with an Ok button. but the problem is when I click on that OK button I do not get anything.  Ideally I should be getting another alert box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {        
        alert("here");              
        $.post('process.php', {name:'test1',email:'test.com'}, function(data)
        {
            $('#results').html(data);
            alert(data);
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="results"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

**Edit:** I found out that Internet Explorer which has HTTP works perfectly fine but not on Internet Explorer which uses HTTPS.

Comment: Click event for a submit button is not logically correct..for click you have to use normal button

Comment: And, why are you using an old version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
function validate(elem){
    $.post('process.php', {name:'test1',email:'test.com'}, function(data)
            {
                $('#results').html(data);
                return true;
            });
    return false;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any other change that i need to do in the program ?

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery `$.ajax()` for posting your form data using `$(fomname).serialize()` method

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitYourForm()
{
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                async:true,
                url: 'your url',
                data: $('#myform').serialize(), 
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
               });      
}
```

change your button type from "submit" to "button" and call your function onclick the button 
like

```
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="submitYourForm();" value="Submit" />
```

remove function call onsubmit.

try this